# mapStateToProps вложенный объект

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день. В приведенном примере ниже я осуществляю connect  в react приложении с состоянием redux. Если я правильно понимаю, то функция mapStateToProps не только добавляет данные из состояний в props, но она и отвечает за рендеринг компонента.

То есть компонент отрендериться только тогда, когда mapStateToProps  вернет объект отличный от предыдущего вызова.

```
const mapStateToProps = function (store, props) {
    return {
        leagues: store.sport[props.sid]
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sport);
```

Но что делать , если я хочу передать в качестве параметра leagues в компонент объект с данными?

В данном примере я ВСЕГДА возвращал ОДИНАКОВЫЙ объект leagues, но рендеринг все равно выполнялся. Получается когда мы возвращаем объект, редукс не может его сравнить с предыдущим и вызывает render() ?

Вопрос.
Как возвращать объект в mapStateToProps leagues, и при этом чтобы рендеринг компонента не выполнялся лишний раз.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` выполняет преобразование состояния, которое собирается при вызове всех `reducer` в единый объект, который передается в свойства (`props`) компоненту и вызывается каждый раз при обновлении стора-состояния. Обновление стора происходит тогда, когда хоть один из `reducer` возвращает новое состояние-объект.

`mapStateToProps` предотвратит рендер компонента в том случаи если `props` не изменились, а определяет он это с помощью неглубокого сравнения. Неглубокое сравнение это когда проверяется только первый уровень данных.

Именно поэтому в `reducer` состояние должно быть иммутабельным-неизменяемым.

Comment: по вашей логике, нельзя в состояниях хранить даже просто обычный массив? В котором будут перечислены id чего либо

Comment: нет, не так. Вы можете там хранить что угодно, главное чтобы эти данные не мутировали.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере, если рендеринг компонента выполнялся всегда, то это значит, что либо менялись собственные `props` компонента (помимо `sid`), либо содержимое `store.sport[props.sid]`. Посмотрите внимательно, как именно вы обновляете `store.sport` в соответствующем редьюсере.

Comment: Так как все данные приходят сразу, я их сразу и заменяю в редьюсере. Данные приходят аяксом